# Android Studio - how to diff two nested objects in debugger?

Tags: android-studio, android-debug, android-debugging

Let's say I have an object with a lot of nested objects and variables named `credential`:

[image]

After resume program, and re-enter the activity again as different login user:
[image]

What's the best way to diff this two objects all in once ? .e.g `accountName` (String), `isNew` (boolean) variables, and so on.

I tried "Copy Value" and then "Compare Value with Clipboard" but it only able to compare **single text variable**. "View Text" is same.

I also tried "Mark Object...", but its object will lose and not permanently store(re-enter class will override the object):

[image]

So is there any way to compare two complex and nested object values ?

**[UPDATE]**

I figure out I can press <kbd>shift</kbd> OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to highlight all and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, but still it will not included nested object without expand them one by one:

[image]

**[UPDATE 2]:**

I noticed `shadow$__klass_` object seems like contains itself and cause endless nested attributes. But it can be solved if I can exclude this object name OR limit the max nested depth ?

Answer (score 1):

You can develop utility method and keep it somewhere in your project which accepts two objects and call it in the eval expression debugger window and see the difference.

You can use some reflection library or develop your own, it could work this way: walk over the object fields by reflection and build the map where the key contains the composite path of fields (f.e. `fieldA.fieldANested.number`) and the value it has. Then that two maps for the two objects could be compared very easily and you can see the difference in your debugger

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a quick way to diff any 2 objects nested attributes without add a lot of thing in my code.

Comment: You can keep that utility code temporary in you project